# Is there A Way To Format Serialized Response for Groups and their Permissions in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I created an API endpoint in which I am sending a JSON data. to create a group and then assigned permission to the models (e.g add_user, change_user etc) programmatically.

It works fine.

The issue now is that I will like to format data retrieved in the same format I sent it in

This is for the Django's inbuilt Group, Permissions, ContentType

**View.py**

```
class RolePermissionListCreateAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    
    queryset = Group.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RolePermissionSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)


    def list(self, request):
        if not request.user.has_perm("auth.view_group"):
            return Response({"error":"Permission denied."}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = RolePermissionSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**Serializer.py**

```
class PermissionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    codename = serializers.CharField(allow_blank=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Permission
        fields ="__all__"

class RolePermissionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = CharField(max_length=100)
    permissions = PermissionSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ["id", "name", "permissions"]
```

**Data**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Administrator",
        "permissions": [
            {
                "codename": "add_user"
            },
            {
                "codename": "change_user"
            },
            {
                "codename": "deactivate_user"
            },
            {
                "codename": "delete_user"
            },
            {
                "codename": "export_user"
            },
            {
                "codename": "import_user"
            },
            {
                "codename": "print_user"
            },
            {
                "codename": "view_user"
            }
            
        ]
    }
]
```

This actually the way I want the data to be formatted:

```
{
    "role_name": "Administrator",
    "modules": [
        {
        "module_name": "User",
        "can_view": "True",
        "can_add": "True",
        "can_edit": "True",
        "can_delete": "True",
        "can_print": "True",
        "can_deactivate": "True",
        "can_import": "True",
        "can_export": "True"
        }
]
}
```

Please, every help and suggestions will go a long way.

Comment: Do you just need to take in the 1st dictionary you have listed above, and create the second?

Comment: I want to create the format of the second from the first.

Answer (score 0):

In Serializer there is a method called to_represetation you can override the Response

```
def to_representation(self, instance):
    response = super().to_representation(instance)
    # response is the dictionary you can overwrite it accordingly

   
    return response
```

Comment: I am not familier with to_represent method but I will look into it. Thanks @Harshil shrivasta

Comment: Is it possible to have 
```
"codename": "add_user",
"codename": "change_user",
"codename": "view_user",
````
changed to
````
"module_name":"user",
"can_add":True,
"can_edit":True,
"can_view":True,
...
```

Comment: @o3cloud yes, but this is not specifically a django problem  You should google "python loop over dictionary" or some such thing.